# i get rollback when i try to sign_up on my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rollback

the problem block my work for 5 days now.
Okay, i try to add the customize fields with devise gem

I try to add additional fields to the gem devise when registering and editing the user profile:

*# sign up: [:username, :contact, :terms, :status]
*# account_update : [:username, :contact, :status, :terms,
:gender, :city, :school_name, :level_class, :resume, :matiere_shared, :matricule, :avatar]**

to add this feature, I started with the currency doc, but I still have a rollback and impossible to do the registration

my  ApplicationController

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected
     def configure_permitted_parameters
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :contact, :terms, :status])
          devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username, :contact, :status, :terms,
           :gender, :city, :school_name, :level_class, :resume, :matiere_shared, :matricule, :avatar])
        end

    end
```

**models code**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord


  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :matieres, through: :courses
  has_many :comments, through: :courses
  belongs_to :level

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable  and :omniauthable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable, :invitable


  #Slug
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
  end

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      username_changed?
  end  

end
```

**route code**

```
  devise_for :users
```

**terminal code**

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2019-12-28 20:13:16 +0000
Processing by DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vAwU5I4v71IYsXh2BoTN6j0zwjmrVL04FsHiKlTctaQ90MJaweZYAaS0O0ks0EmnznqoBMbJBX/tIixkf6ZlsA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"vakaramoko@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "vakaramoko@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/chatln/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /home/chatln/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "vakaramoko@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/chatln/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ /home/chatln/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.3ms)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/links/_links-top.html.erb (9.3ms)
  Rendered shared/devise/_notification.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/nav/_navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/links/_links-js.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 465ms (Views: 104.6ms | ActiveRecord: 15.6ms)
```

I reimplemented in a new app all run good, not problem, but with my great app impossible. please helps me

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is that the user already exists:

```
User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "vakaramoko@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Try to find it through the console:

```
$ rails c
$ User.find_by(email: 'vakaramoko@gmail.com')
```

Comment: think you tot try help me. I undertand, you try to verify if this email exist.  but the  result is ** nil***

Comment: the link to repos depot. [https://github.com/VAKARAMOKO/chatln]

Answer (score 0):

From the logs the user registration is processed by DeviseInvitable and the parameters shown doesn't even include the additional fields that you have added. You need to permit the those parameters for also invitable module. 
Try adding this under `configure_permitted_parameters` method:

```
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation,
                                    keys: %i[username contact terms status])
```

If you didn't mean to use invitable just remove it from devise options in user model.

Comment: thank you to interest me. but nothing change. i delete devise invitable feature on my app